# Xcode: Building to iPhone fails because of 2 Apple Mach-O Linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode

The problem is described in the title. The error message is this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "OBJC_CLASS$_OneSignal", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OneSignalUnityRuntime.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Clearing the `DerivedData folder` didn't solve the problem.**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a library / framework from Unity, and presumably it doesn't have an `armv7` slice. Make sure you are using the latest version of the the library / framework and that you have removed any outdated version.

Comment: I've explained, I think, the cause of the problem. Solving it is up to you. He who lives by the third-party library dies by the third-party library, after all. Please do your own work. This has come up numerous times before here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unity+undefined+symbols+for+architecture